# I have got no error regarding syntax but the app doesn't work

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I am trying to make a tabbar and include some pages to each tab. I do not get errors and the Simulator runs the app, however, it only shows the tabbar and its animation and not other pages that I need.

I had some errors when I had the Widget buildPages at the button of the page, so I related the widget code under class _MyAppState.

I am not sure which part of the code is dislocated or if there is any extra function like var index;

```
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gg/tabBarScreens/Following.dart';
import 'package:gg/tabBarScreens/Liked%20Albums.dart';
import 'package:gg/tabBarScreens/profileTabBar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  //State class
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int page = 0;
  
  Widget buildPages(){
    var index;
    switch (index){
      case 2:
        return profileTabBar();
      case 1:
        return likedAlbums();
      case 0:
      default: 0;
      return Following();
    }
  }

  GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: _bottomNavigationKey,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              page = index;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: buildPages(),


    ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your buildPages function remove "var index" and inside [switch statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_switch_case_statement.htm) replace your variable_expression to page

```
  Widget buildPages() {
    switch (page) {
      case 2:
        return profileTabBar();
      case 1:
        return likedAlbums();
      case 0:
        return Following();
      default:
        return Following();
    }
  }
```

Full code for a basic working example, which you can even paste [here](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) and see it in action

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  //State class
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int page = 0;

  Widget buildPages() {
    switch (page) {
      case 2:
        return Container(color: Colors.red);
      case 1:
        return Container(color: Colors.blue);
      case 0:
        return Container(color: Colors.green);

      default:
        return Container(color: Colors.green);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: "",
              icon: Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: "",
              icon: Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: "",
              icon: Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              page = index;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: buildPages(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Third tab is tapped
[image]

First tab is tapped
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort mate.
I have tried your altered code, it puts all of them in a single tab which happened to be the last. I was trying those pages in different tabs!
For example; Following in the first tab, and the Followers in the second...

Comment: I updated the answer. In case if this is not what you were looking for, please provide more details and more explained example.

Comment: I need the CurvedNavigationBar to load different pages in different tabs. For instance, when the last icon on tabbar is tapped, show Following or Followers pages which I have made and imported.
thanks

Comment: Different pages are loaded based on Scaffold's body parameter, so it doesn't really matter